# what could be the reason _set is not created on FK relation creation in Django?

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-related-manager

I have the following data structure

```
class A(models.Model):
   a number of fields here

class AbstractParent(models.Model):
   some fields here

   class Meta:
       abstract = True

class B(AbstractParent):
   a = ForeignKey(A, null=True,default=None, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

I would expect to access the object of B class that fk to an instance of A `a` via `a.b_set` or `a.bs_set` however I only get the error that attribute `b_set` does not exist for `a`. Any ideas why this is possible and how to access `b` that references `a` via `a` itself?

Comment: Can you access `a` from `B` instances? What is the output of `A._meta.related_objects` and `B._meta.related_objects`?

Comment: You should probably show your real code. This is likely dependent on something you're not showing us.

Comment: That should work. Have you tried setting a related name on the foreign key and using that?

Comment: @EndreBoth yes, accessing a from b instances works fine. b.a returns an object, to which b fk's. b._meta.related_objects is expectedly empty, while a._meta.related_objects returns a whole bunch of relations (it's a big project) including  <ManyToOneRel: module_name.a>.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'd love to show the code, but it's a large closed-source  project.

Comment: @mikeyj this can be fixed, but I'd really love to understand how it is possible in the first place.

Comment: Then run `A._meta.related_objects[x].related_name` for a surprise (`x` being the appropriate numerical index for the `<ManyToOneRel: module_name.a>` relation; you can also run a `for ... in`.

Comment: Wait, is A's related object `<ManyToOneRel: module_name.*a*>` or `<ManyToOneRel: module_name.*b*>`? It should be the latter (the former would imply a fk relationship to self).

Comment: @EndreBoth surprising indeed, `related_name` was `None` =)

Comment: Fascinating (but it only means that no `related_name` is set as a field option). I assume that it works fine if you set a related name on `B.a`?